# How to check for specific Observable calling update() in mvc approach in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

at the moment i am learning to seperate my code in mcv manner. In my MainView Class i have an Object "InputPanelView" that consists of a TextField and a Button.
In addition i have a Label in my MainView that i want to put in front of this panel. When clicking on the button, the label should get updated to match the text of the TextField.

Here is my MainView

```
public class MainView extends JFrame implements Observer{

/**
* 
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3923069538840783335L;

private JLabel lbl;

private InputPanelView view;
private MainController mainController;
private MainModel mainModel;
public MainView() {
    mainModel = new MainModel();
    lbl = new JLabel();
    mainController = new MainController(this, mainModel);

    setSize(200, 70);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    setContentPane(panel);

    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
    view = new InputPanelView();
    view.getModel().addObserver(this);

    innerPanel.add(lbl);
    innerPanel.add(view);
    panel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public JLabel getLbl() {
    return lbl;
}

@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    //Check which InputPanelView was clicked
    }
}
```

My InputPanelView:

```
public class InputPanelView extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3399831219930321653L;
private TextField textField;
private JButton inputButton;
private InputPanelModel model;
private InputPanelController controller;

public InputPanelView() {
    super(new GridBagLayout());
    model = new InputPanelModel();
    controller = new InputPanelController(this, model);

}

public TextField getTextField() {
    return textField;
}

public JButton getInputButton() {
    return inputButton;
}

public void createView() {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0d;
    textField = new TextField();
    add(textField, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbc.weightx = 0.0d;
    inputButton = new JButton();

    add(inputButton, gbc);

}

public InputPanelModel getModel() {
    return model;

}
```

And my InputPanelController:

```
public class InputPanelController implements ActionListener {
private InputPanelModel model;
private InputPanelView view;

public InputPanelController(InputPanelView inputPanelView, InputPanelModel model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = inputPanelView;
    this.view.createView();
    this.view.getInputButton().setText(this.model.getBtnText());
    this.view.getInputButton().addActionListener(this);
    this.view.getTextField().setText(this.model.getTxtText());

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == view.getInputButton()) {
        model.setTxtText(view.getTextField().getText());

    }
}

public InputPanelView getView() {
    return view;
}
```

It works as intended but if i add another InputPanelView to the MainView with another Label, how can i check in the update() method which Label i should change respectively which InputPanelView's button was clicked?

I am not a native speaker, hope its understandable.

Regards

Comment: Are you meaning Java 9's [`java.util.Observable`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html), or JavaFX's [`javafx.beans.Observable`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html).  Or your own custom `Observable`?  (Mixing JavaFX and Swing is a bad idea.)

Comment: I am using Java9's Observable

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I saw (since="9") on the `java.util.Observable` class, and thought that was introduced in Java 9.  It is actually **deprecated** starting at Java 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of implementing `Observer` in `MainView`, and using the main view as an `Observer` ...

```
view.getModel().addObserver(this);
```

... use more than one `Observer`:

```
view.getModel().addObserver(new Observer() {
   @Override
   void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
      updateView1(arg0, arg1);
   }
});

view2.getModel().addObserver(new Observer() {
   @Override
   void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
      updateView2(arg0, arg1);
   }
});
```

Then, `MainView` does not need to implement `Observer`.